# What ever happened to the X.Commerce Fabric?

Tags: xcommerce

Is the public Fabric still in development? Are there interesting services that you use? Have Magento/eBay really stalled out development at this point?

Comment: i have asked insiders to see if there is any official statement. Will update this entry as soon as I get one.

Comment: Evaporation seems to be the order of the day on this one. As happened with the various ERP connectors back when.

Comment: Yeah - Bridge just *poof* disappeared.

Comment: The product was officially sunset in 2013 as eBay  announced at Magento Imagine. New product direction moves all of this functionality to the Magento platform. PayPal Here and many other recent acquisitions (RedLaser, etc) will be providing Magento support in the coming months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's on-hold, focus is on Magento 2.

Social Media activity:

- twitter - last tweet 29th November 2012
- facebook - 9th Nov 2012
- blog ([Devzone](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/rise-telco-ultimate-app-digital-storefront-really)) - 28th Sept 2012

Support answers to some queries on forums, with huge delay (1 month)

It looks halted for now...

Answer (score 1):

This project was officially closed in January of this year.

Comment: Vinai said something similar during Checkout III - any official documentation on this?

Comment: What would you consider official documentation? I got a word from Magento core team member during Magento Hackathon in Zurich.